# SharePoint Summary Links Web Part Content Not Being Indexed

Tags: search, sharepoint, hyperlink, summary

Terms: SharePoint 2013, Summary Link Web Part, SLWP, search, index

Several customers have created a page with Summary Links Web Parts (SLWP) for a list of URI’s.  The title of the SLWP in indexed in the search engine, but all of the links are not.  I have done multiple searches on this topic (even back to SP2010 and SP2007), but have not found an answer.

I did run across a statement about being able to use audiences to display only those links that they can see, figuring maybe that the SE will not index because of all of the variations.

There are not any settings in the web part that I can find for a workaround, wondering if anybody else has seen this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the "Links" (previously called Summary Links for SP2010 I guess) webpart. It stores the link in a list called "Links" in a field with Static Name "URL" or maybe ows_URL. 
There is a possibility that this field is not indexed because the field ows_URL is not added as managed property in the Search Schema, if it is not it should be added and full crawl should be performed after.
Another reason that the search does not index might be because the "Allow items from this list to appear in search results? " option for the list is set to "No" then the search would ignore this list. This option can be found in List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Allow items from this list to appear in search results?.
Another reason might be a custom crawl rule that prevents indexing this.

I tested searching for Links item on SharePoint Server with OOTB Search settings and OOTB Links list. It showed results for item created in the "Links" list so one of the above might be changed.